# In Dax, how can i count values in one column that equal the value of another column?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two columns, i want a table that shows the number of "Assign Date" in "Week Start" so for "Week Start" of 1/1/2022 it should be 0, for "Week Start" of 1/7/2022, it should be 2, and it should be 1 for 1/14/2022 and 1/21/2022.

I have two date column

| Week Start | Assign Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2022 | 1/8/2022 |
| 1/8/2022 | 1/8/2022 |
| 1/15/2022 | 1/15/2022 |
| 1/22/2022 | 1/22/2022 |

I want one date column and one count column

| Week Start | Assign Count |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2022 | 0 |
| 1/8/2022 | 2 |
| 1/15/2022 | 1 |
| 1/22/2022 | 1 |

I am very new to DAX and i assume that i am over complicating the solution but i can't figure out where to start. Because i am learning DAX, i would like to get this in a DAX measure.

Comment: What day of the week is the first day? From what you write, it appears as if your first week only has six days.  Or is there an error in your table?

Comment: I just had a typo on the first date in the first table, thank you for letting me know

Comment: It'd be pretty easy to add a column in Power Query. But I see you are looking in particular for a DAX solution.

Comment: Could you help me using power query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or this **measure**:

```
Assign Count :=
VAR ThisWeekStart =
    MIN( Table1[Week Start] )
RETURN
    0
        + COUNTROWS(
            FILTER(
                ALL( Table1 ),
                Table1[Assign Date] = ThisWeekStart
            )
        )
```

which you can place in a visual together with the *Week Start* field.

Answer (score 0):

There may be more efficient M-Code, but what I did here was
to use List.Accumulate to count the number of entries that were in the correct range: `>=Week Start` and `<Week Start + 7 days`

***M Code***

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Week Start", type date}, {"Assign Date", type date}}),

    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Assign Count", 
        each List.Accumulate(
                #"Changed Type"[Assign Date],
                0,
                (state, current)=> 
                    if current >=[Week Start] and current < Date.AddDays([Week Start],7) then state +1 else state)),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Assign Date"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]